# Разница функции и процедуры в python?

Tags: python, функции

Функция должна принимать аргументы и возвращать какие-то данные. Почему в этом коде функция работает по факту как процедура, изменяя аргументы, которые были поданы? Спасибо

````
def cofactor(array, i, q): #алгебраическое дополнение ((−1)^(i+j) * Mi,j)
    for k in range(i):
        array[k].pop(q)
    array.pop(i)
    return array
    #return (-1)**(i + q) * determinant(array)

array = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]  

for i in range(3):
    for q in range(3):
        print('array: ', array)
        print(cofactor(array, i, q))```
````

Comment: @DmitriyNovikov как как?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В питоне нет понятия процедуры, только функции и методы (это функции у классов).

И объекты в нем передаются по ссылке.

Кроме того, список `array` является изменяемыми, поэтому, если не хотите поменять его внутри функции и вернуть измененную копию, то сделайте копирование списка через [copy.deepcopy](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy):

```
import copy

def cofactor(array, i, q): #алгебраическое дополнение ((−1)^(i+j) * Mi,j)
    array = copy.deepcopy(array)

    for k in range(i):
        array[k].pop(q)
    array.pop(i)
    return array
```

Comment: Спасибо. А без модуля copy это реально сделать?

Comment: Я бы не сказал, что это передача «по ссылке». Передаётся имя ссылающееся на тот же объект в памяти. `array = []` никак не затрагивает переданный аргумент. Впрочем, это вопрос терминологии))

Comment: @EgorFedorov, можно, нужно заново воссоздать список списков, что-то вроде такого: `array = [[x for x in array[i]] for i in range(len(array))]`, короткий вариант `array = [list(x) for x in array]`

Answer (score 0):

В питоне вообще нет разницы между функцией и процедурой. В питоне даже если вы ничего не вернёте с помощью `return` в явном виде, по факту вернётся значение `None`.

Далее. В других языках точно такая же история с ссылочными типами, переданными в процедуру/функцию, которое вы наблюдаете в этом коде: вы не можете поменять сам указатель на переданный объект, но вы легко можете поменять его содержимое.

Да, это не очень хороший стиль, когда процедура/функция меняет что-то переданное ей, чего вы не ожидаете, но от такого поведения нет никакой страховки.